# DBI1011I Error when using db2iupdt to enable Text Search

Tags: db2, full-text-search

I'm trying to [enable Text Search](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ts.doc%2Fdoc%2Ft0052968.html) in my DB2 instance. I'm running this command:

```
# /opt/ibm/db2/V10.5/instance/db2iupdt db2inst1 -j "TEXT_SEARCH,db2j_db2inst1,55000"
```

I get this error:

```
DBI1011I  An invalid argument was entered for the db2iupdt command.

Explanation:

You can use the db2iupdt command to update a DB2 instance to a higher
level within a release, convert a DB2 instance to a DB2 pureScale
instance, or manage DB2 members or cluster caching facilities (CFs) of a
DB2 pureScale instance.

This message is returned when the db2iupdt command is invoked with
incorrect or missing parameters.

User response:

Enter the command again using valid parameters.


   Related information:
   db2iupdt - Update instances command
   Updating an instance to a higher level within a release using the
   db2iupdt command
   Updating an instance to a DB2 pureScale instance with the db2iupdt
   command
   Dropping a member or cluster caching facility
   Adding new members or an additional cluster caching facility
```

[DBI1011I documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.messages.dbi.doc%2Fdoc%2Fmdbi01011i.html&resultof%3D%2522%2544%2542%2549%2531%2530%2531%2531%2549%2522%2520%2522%2564%2562%2569%2531%2530%2531%2531%2569%2522%2520) just says there's something wrong with the parameters. I'm not seeing anything obviously wrong with them when looking at the documentation for [db2iupdt](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0002060.html).

I'm running DB2 10.5:

```
$ db2licm -l
Product name:                     "DB2 Advanced Workgroup Server Edition"
License type:                     "CPU Option"
Expiry date:                      "Permanent"
Product identifier:               "db2awse"
Version information:              "10.5"
Max amount of memory (GB):        "128"
Enforcement policy:               "Soft Stop"
```

How do I successfully enable Text Search in my DB2 instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux, the instance name has to be the last thing in the [db2iupdt command](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0002060.html):

```
# /opt/ibm/db2/V10.5/instance/db2iupdt -j "TEXT_SEARCH,db2j_db2inst1,55000" db2inst1
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the syntax diagram at http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002060.html, you should enclose the text search options in double quotation marks:

```
-j "TEXT_SEARCH,db2j_db2inst1,55000"
```

Don't forget to escape them in the shell.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same error with `/opt/ibm/db2/V10.5/instance/db2iupdt db2inst1 -j "TEXT_SEARCH,db2j_db2inst1,55000"`. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Also, same error with shell-escaped `/opt/ibm/db2/V10.5/instance/db2iupdt db2inst1 -j \"TEXT_SEARCH,db2j_db2inst1,55000\"`

Comment: Shouldn't the instance name come _after_ the option?

Comment: You're right, that's the issue. On Linux, the instance name has to be the last thing on the command line. The Information Center is pretty confusing on this: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0002060.html